# Powershell Batch Folder Rename-Item - limit length and standardize

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a set of folders that need to be standardized in their naming convention.

Currently the folders are named as such:

> 12345 - Project 1 Long name long name long name long long name
>
> 1245346-Project 2 long name too long name is too long
>
> 1247 Project 3 name goes here

I'm currently using this script:

```
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Path -Directory | 
ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name | Out-File "$($_.FullName)\$($_.Name).txt" -Force
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name -replace '^(\d+).*$', '$1')
}
```

This script correctly will do the following:

> 1. Write a text file inside each folder with the current name of the folder
> 2. Rename the folder only keeping the numbers

I'd like it so that the script can do this:

> 1. Write a text file inside each folder with the current name of the folder
> 2. Rename the folder to the standard "111111 - Project Name Max 60 characters" (ProjectNumber[space][dash][space]Remaining current text
>      limited to 60 characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate the differing delimiters you'll need two groups

```
-NewName ($_.Name -replace "^(\d+)[\s-_]+(Project.{0,$MaxLength}).*$",'$1 - $2')
```

Comment: I do seem to have some projects with an underscore after the number eg:

12012_Project Name

Is there a simple way to grab 'all numbers ' then ignore anything until [a-zA-Z] then combine them with the - in the middle? (keeping the character limit as well)

Comment: Then include the underscore in the class of chars from which at least one has to be present. I'll change it above.

Comment: Or provided the word `Project` is always present put `.+` between the two capture groups. `-NewName ($_.Name -replace '^(\d+).+(Project.{0,53}).*$', '$1 - $2')`

Comment: Thanks! This helped me edit for my use case (I don't actually have 'Project' in the title, so the final code I have for this is

`Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ($_.Name -replace '^(\d+)[\s-_]+(.{0,40}).*$', '$1 - $2')`

Last question - is there any way to put a variable inside of the regex? So I can put the length as $maxlength and easily change it?

Comment: Yes but to expand the variable enclose the match part in double quotes (not the replace part otherwise the `$1` substitution won't work)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace your regex with

```
'^(\d+\s*-\s*.{0,60}).*'
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+\s*-\s*.{0,60})` - Group 1:

  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  - `\s*-\s*` - a hyphen enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
  - `.{0,60}` - any 0 to 60 chars other than newline
- `.*` - any 0+ chars up to the end of the line

The `$1` backreference will only keep the value captured by Group 1.